# "Cannot read property ... of null" when trying to read ajax data (but it still works)

Tags: angular

I'm trying to read JSON data from an API and display its contents on screen.

So I have a simple service like this:

```js
export interface Post {
  userId: number,
  id: number,
  title: string,
  body: string
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor() { }

  public getPost(): Observable<Post> {
    return <Observable<Post>>ajax.getJSON('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');
  }
}
```

And a component like this:

```js
export class PostComponent implements OnInit {

  public post$ : Observable<Post>;

  constructor(
    private apiService : ApiService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.post$ = this.apiService.getPost();
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Data returned from the server:</p>
<p>Title: {{(post$ | async).title}}</p>
```

It works as expected, but get several of these error messages on the console:

```
core.js:6260 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of null
    at PostComponent_Template (post.component.html:2)
(...)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably your observable is sending `null` initially before the correct value.

Comment: Just use {{(post$ | async)?.title}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change detection might be triggered multiple times in a template expression. Try to wrap it using a `*ngIf` directive in a container

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(post$ | async) as post">
  <p>Data returned from the server:</p>
  <p>Title: {{ post?.title }}</p>
</ng-container>
```

The `<ng-container>` doesn't create additional elements in the DOM. They are compiled into comments. The safe navigation operator [`?.`](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator) makes sure `post` is defined before trying to access it's properties. (As @JohnMontgomery pointed in the comments, it is redundant here since we also check beforehand using the `*ngIf` directive).

<sub>Besides if there isn't any good reason to use Ajax, you could try to use Angular [HttpClient](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient).</sub>

Comment: Seems kind of redundant to use `*ngIf` *and* `?.`, isn't it?

Comment: That is true, but it might introduce OP to the safe navigation operator. I'll include the comment in the answer.